# Securing REST API for mobile use with OAuth

Tags: android, oauth, rest

I'm a complete noob about security, so please, forgive me if I say something wrong.

I have to develop a social network. The client will be an Android app and (probably) a web page for smartphones that will use a REST API. Because of the characteristics of the social network, if the info of an user is stolen, it's not very important, but, I have to identify every user by username/password login and I have to be sure that every message comes from the legit user.

I don't want to use SSL (TLS) because I don't have many resources, so I don't want to suffer the latency of SSL and I don't want to pay for the certificate. So, it would be a good idea to use OAuth for securying the REST API? Are there any better approaches?

Comment: You might want to read up on Man In The Middle (MITM) attacks. If you authenticate, but fail to secure the session, the authentication is wasted effort.

Comment: Ok, MITM is something that worries me. How can I avoid it without using SSL? Is it possible?

Comment: @Alex Text why would anyone try to do this without SSL/TLS?  (this is not possible)

Answer (score 1):

HTTPS is an absolute requirement for authenticated communication.  [HTTPS typically increases CPU demands by less than 2%](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache%3aKfBOYogfmNIJ%3ahttps://www.verisign.com.au/ssl/ssl-information-center/ssl-resources/whitepaper-protect-sidejacking/firesheep-sidejacking.pdf%20&hl=en&gl=us&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESg0KMGygXk85wV5u-3fx2VBPe74kT38mvlKPR-LjoPCBqoAmUmUF3jzAlHQ3o2rG8DU8LG7v3zSo3ltjb7OFZ30L25f5SmBIwPXxQXmAFbJHS-FDMintQ7iPiIfEmeUe5oYwVxX&sig=AHIEtbTv8by4rOFTS9KJdG_SF-h27OHoCQ&pli=1),  and other than the initial handshake HTTPS will not increase network letancy.   Without HTTPS you are in violation of [OWASP - Insufficient Transport Layer Security](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Periodic_Table_of_Vulnerabilities_-_Insufficient_Transport_Layer_Protection).  Security isn't just HTTPS,  if you are "securing a REST API",  you have to worry about other vulenrablites and the OWASP top 10 is a good palce to start.

(On a side note,  after so many years I'm still surprised that people think HTTPS is optional, and that somehow encryption is this huge burden. I can perform a few million AES operations per second,  and most of the time I can't load a web page in under a second.  Why do people think encryption is heavy?  I would like an explanation.)

Comment: it's one of those myths, sadly. The myth that encryption is this devious, crazy, computationally expensive thing (which it can be, by the way), which is not helped by non-technical people writing articles confusing encryption and hashing and saying that it is computationally expensive to "decrypt hashes", for instance. All of it is hearsay :-( HTTPS requires one more hop, a couple extra if you're verifying the full CA chain, but very few agents should ever do this.